# JComboBox with error upon dropdown - Java

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox

I am having issues with my jcombo box when accessing the list from the gui.

The combobox was placed using a netbeans designer to take string items.

I then populated the combobox like this:

```
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> userInfoCombo;

public List getSchoolList() throws IOException {

    Map<String, List<String>> schoolMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    schoolMap = schoolMapCreator.updateList();

    List<String> schoolNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (List<String> value : schoolMap.values()) {
        String schoolName = value.get(1);
        schoolNameList.add(schoolName);
    }

    userInfoCombo.removeAllItems();

    //for (String schoolName : schoolNameList) {
        //userInfoCombo.addItem(schoolName);
    //}

    //with SO user suggestion update--same error comes up
    userInfoCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(schoolNameList.toArray()));

    System.out.println("Get School Name List : -----------> " + schoolNameList);
    return schoolNameList;
}
```

When starting up the gui and calling getSchoolList, I see the first value in the list as a choice in the combobox. When pressing the arrow to see the other choices, however, I get the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:153)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.paintComponent(AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:227)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:153)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.paintComponent(AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:227)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:153)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.paintComponent(AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:227)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**UPDATE** This error also occurs when I try populating the combobox with a simple list of strings, so I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the way I have added values to the list previously. This error also occurs if I add a combo and populate it using the Gui Model.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (List<String> value : schoolMap.values()) {
    //String schoolName = value.get(1);
    schoolNameList.add(value.get(1));
   }

     //userInfoCombo.removeAllItems(); no need to remove all

    //for (String schoolName : schoolNameList) {
       // userInfoCombo.addItem(schoolName);
    //}

   userInfoCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(schoolNameList.toArray()));
```

you dont have to iterate over the list to set values to a combobox use a defaultcombobox model

Comment: The schoolMap.values() are of List<String>. I need to get the 1 index element of each list, so the for loop was giving me what i need. using your code does not eliminate the error mentioned in the question, and the combo box is not populated with the intended item strings.

Comment: made some changes. try it now.

Comment: @Priyamai, I still get that NullPointerException when pressing the arrow, with the first value correctly populated in the combobox.

Comment: @Priyamai See edits--I don't think it's due to the for loop, because even if I try populating the combo with a simple list of strings.toArray() the errors occur

Comment: I think the error has something to do with the theme in your project . Try changing your current theme and give it a try.